# Issue with tabular environment

Tags: tables

As I am currently tutoring a calculus student, I am creating a mock exam in LaTeX. I have a question concerning a portion of my code which I have displayed below, though, I do not know if displaying my code helps at all in any way. (See the very bottom of this post for my question.)

```
\textbf{Integral Identities} (and some more Derivative Identities)

Write the identities for the following indefinite integrals or derivatives in problems 5-10. In this section, you are encouraged to consult your textbook or any resource available. \textit{No work is required to be shown.}

Do not forget about the $+C$ which is required for indefinite integrals!

\begin{enumerate}
\item[5.] If $n$ is an integer, then $\displaystyle \int x^n \, dx=\begin{cases} \frac 1{n+1}x^{n+1}+C &\text{if }n \not= -1 \\ \ln|x|+C & \text{if }n = -1 \end{cases}$. 

\textbf{Hint: }We must consider two cases here.
\begin{itemize}
\item If $n \not=1$, simply state the Anti-Power Rule, which is the exact opposite of the Power Rule which you saw in problem 1. Observe that the Anti-Power Rule does \textit{not} work if $n = -1$; try it anyway with $n=-1$ and you will see why it fails. 
\item For the case of $n=-1$, refer to problem 4 for a hint. For whatever antiderivative you write in the second blank, place the absolute value bars around the $x$, like this: $|x|$. This is due to a mathematical technicality for the integration of $x^{-1}$.
\end{itemize}

\item[6.]  Evaluate: $\displaystyle \int e^x \, dx = e^x+C$.

\item[7.] What are the derivative identities for the following? You may wish consult your textbook as necessary. (Yes, part i. was shown already in problem 3.)
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
i. $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\sin x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & ii. $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\cos x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ \\
iii.  $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(-\sin x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & iv.  $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(-\cos x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\item[8.] What are the integral identities for the following? Use problem 7 for clues.
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
i. $\displaystyle \int \sin x \, dx  = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & ii. $\displaystyle \int \cos x \, dx = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ \\
iii.  $\displaystyle \int -\sin x \, dx = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & iv.  $\displaystyle \int -\cos x \, dx = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\item[9.] What are the derivative identities for the following?
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
i. $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\tan x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & ii. $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\cot x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ \\
iii.  $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\csc x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & iv.  $\displaystyle \frac d{dx}(\sec x) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\item[10.] What are the integral identities for the following? 

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
i. $\displaystyle \int \tan x \, dx  = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & ii. $\displaystyle \int \cot x \, dx) = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ \\
iii.  $\displaystyle \int \csc x \, dx = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$ & iv.  $\displaystyle \int \sec x \, dx = \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\item[11.] Write the formula for this integral: $\displaystyle \int \ln x \, dx=         \underline{\hspace{4cm}}$. Use your textbook or some other resource if needed. (I probably     said this enough already, haven't I? :D)

\end{enumerate}

\newpage
```

I want the tables to correspond with my question numbers 7,8,9,10 respectively. The table for my question #10 is being stupid, and that table of integrals is instead outputted to the next page. Any possible reason why this is happening? As in, why is this table not appearing below question #10 as I wanted? I am so confused right now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just don't use `table`, but `center`.

Comment: `table` is a floating environment: you were telling LaTeX to set the tabular wherever it thinks fit. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/)